# circe, DecodingFailure while decoding List[SomeCaseClass]

Tags: scala, circe

I have a case class with a `List` of another case class, like this:

`final case class Nested(p1: String, p2: String)`

`final case class Outer(str: Option[String], lst: Option[List[Nested]])`

I've created `Encoder` and `Decoder` for each of these classes (implicit vals).

Now, when I try to do this:

`val decodedEither = decode[Outer](jsonString)`

I get an error like this:

> DecodingFailure(Type does not match expected: Outer, List())

My imports:

```
import io.circe.Decoder.Result
import io.circe._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._
import cats.syntax.show._
```

It's a general example, the actual class names are different, I just isolated an error in a more complicated case, then tried very simple JSON and classes (almost like the ones above). So, the problem occurs when a field is a `List`.

Does anyone know what is missing and how to make `circe` parse JSON using case classes with `List` (and `Set`) fields?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `Decoder.forProductN()` methods to create the decoders instead of using `Decoder.instance()`. I don't know why but it solved the problem, although there are both variants used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some issue either with how you defined codecs or with the json

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto
import io.circe.parser.decode

final case class Nested(p1: String, p2: String)
object Nested {
  implicit val dec: Decoder[Nested] = semiauto.deriveDecoder[Nested]
}

final case class Outer(str: Option[String], lst: Option[List[Nested]])
object Outer {
  implicit val dec: Decoder[Outer] = semiauto.deriveDecoder[Outer]
}

val jsonString =
  """
    {"str":"a", "lst":[{"p1":"b", "p2":"c"}, {"p1":"d", "p2":"e"}]}
  """

decode[Outer](jsonString)
// Right(Outer(Some(a),Some(List(Nested(b,c), Nested(d,e)))))
```